# Mysql Group By using column particular single value

Tags: mysql

As Previously I know the mysql group by function , but I really dont know my question is wrong or write, My question how to use group by function using paricular column single value , for ex : consider below datas

```
TAB : tab1
id name  value
1   IN    1
2   IN    1
3   AU    2
4   AU    2
5   IN    3
```

Is it possible to group by using country particular value IN , like below

```
SELECT SUM(value),name FROM tab1 GROUP BY name.IN
```

I expect only ,

```
IN 5
```

If using where condition this would be achieve, but for some reason I need to do this way...but using this way shows error, Is there any other way to achieve this without using where condition , Any help appreciated...

Comment: 'but for some reason' this sounds highly implausible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use having clause.

```
SELECT SUM(value),name FROM tab1 GROUP BY name HAVING name = 'IN'
```